# Literal text not recognized in if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to spit this text out but the view is not recognizing the text "Test1 Test2, test3 test 4":

```
<h3>@if(@user != null){@user.FullName Test1 Test2, Test3 Test4 @user.LastSignIn.}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to surround it with `<text></text>` tags

Comment: Might want? he surly has... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>@if(@user != null){@user.FullName <text>Test1 Test2, Test3 Test4 </text>   
                       @user.LastSignIn.}</h3>
```